# Spark 2.0.0 Error: PartitioningCollection requires all of its partitionings have the same numPartitions

Tags: join, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

I'm joining some DataFrames together in Spark and I keep getting the following error:

```
PartitioningCollection requires all of its partitionings have the same numPartitions.
```

It seems to happen after I join two DataFrames together that each seem fairly reasonable on their own, but after joining them, if I try to get a row from the joined DataFrame, I get this error. I am really just trying to understand why this error might be appearing or what the meaning behind it is as I can't seem to find any documentation on it.

The following invocation results in this exception:

```
val resultDataframe = dataFrame1
  .join(dataFrame2,     
    $"first_column" === $"second_column").take(2)
```

but I can certainly call

```
dataFrame1.take(2)
```

and

```
dataFrame2.take(2)
```

I also tried repartitioning the `DataFrames`, using `Dataset.repartition(numPartitions)` or `Dataset.coalesce(numParitions)` on `dataFrame1` and `dataFrame2` before joining, and on `resultDataFrame` after the join, but nothing seemed to have affected the error. I haven't been able to find reference to other individuals getting the error after some cursory googling...

Answer (score 9):

I have encountered the same issue in the last few days, and I was disappointed when I found no references on the internet. Until yours!

A couple of things I would add: I get the error after a pretty complicated set of operations on dataframes (multiple joins). Also, these operations involve dataframes that are generated from the same parent dataframe. 
I'm trying to have a minimal example to replicate it, but it's not trivial to extract it from my pipeline.

I suspect Spark might be having troubles in computing a correct plan when the DAG gets too complicated.
Unfortunately, it seems that, if it is a bug in Spark 2.0.0, the nightly builds have not fixed it yet (I've tried a 2.0.2 snapshot a couple of days ago).

A **practical solution** that fixes the issue (temporarily) seems to be: write to disk (at some point) some of your dataframes in your pipeline, and read them again. This effectively forces Spark to have a much smaller, more manageable plan to optimize, and well, it doesn't crash anymore. Of course it's just a temporary fix.

Comment: Thank you for your demonstration of consolidarity and what may hopefully be a useful, albeit well-acknowledged-to-be-temporary solution. I'll try this out, but I think there is some possibility that we may have a bug report on our hands if the solution seems out of the grasp of stackoverflow for a bit longer.

Comment: Note also that on version 1.6.x the same code (barring very minor differences) works as intended, not crashing, so it does sound like a bug to me, too.

Comment: Your temporary solution did solve the problem though! I hesitate to mark it as the answer just yet, unless no one else responds otherwise and we decide to head to the spark JIRA, then might as well, but thanks.

Answer (score 9):

I've also had the same problem. For me it occurred after removing some columns from the select part of a join (not the join clause itself).

I was able to fix it by calling `.repartition()` on the dataframe.

Comment: Thanks. This was a better fix than the once above!

Answer (score 3):

Do you call the cache method?

This problem happens to me only when I use cache method.
If I don't call this method I can use the data without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is about `ReorderJoinPredicates` [fixed](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-22042) in Spark 2.3.0